# Custom equality semantics for Immutable.js data structures

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutable.js, sanctuary

I would like [Sanctuary](https://sanctuary.js.org/) to provide [Fantasy Land](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) -compatible Map and Set types with value-based equality semantics. Ideally these values would be immutable, though this is not critical since Sanctuary would provide pure functions for merging and otherwise manipulating these values.

I would love to leverage the good work done by the [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) team; I imagine implementing persistent data structures takes considerable effort!

The API provided by Immutable.js is of little importance since Sanctuary would expose functions for interacting with these values. The equality semantics of these types, though, are crucial.

This is unacceptable for my use case:

```
> Map([[[1, 2, 3], 'foo'], [[1, 2, 3], 'bar']])
Map { [1,2,3]: "foo", [1,2,3]: "bar" }
```

`[1, 2, 3]` is the same value as `[1, 2, 3]`. It should not be possible to have two map entries with the same key.

The handling of `-0` is also problematic:

```
> Immutable.is(Map([[0, 0]]), Map([[-0, -0]]))
true
```

I realize it's possible to define the equality semantics of one's own types by defining `equals` methods, but I wish to redefine the equality semantics of native types such as Array and Number. **Is this possible?** The relevant file appears to be [**is.js**](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/is.js), but I see no hooks for customization.

It's possible that Sanctuary's Map type could wrap the Immutable.js Map type. This would provide:

- a way to handle `-0`;
- an opportunity to perform value-based equality checks before performing an [`assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#assoc) operation which would normally result in a duplicate key; and
- a place to define the various `fantasy-land/` methods.

Perhaps:

```
Map k v = { negativeZero :: Maybe v
          , value :: ImmutableMap k v
          , fantasy-land/equals :: Map k v ~> Map k v -> Boolean
          , fantasy-land/map :: Map k v ~> (k -> a) -> Map a v
          , fantasy-land/bimap :: Map k v ~> (k -> a, v -> b) -> Map a b
          , ...
          }
```

I'd like to be sure there's no other way to attain the desired equality semantics before creating wrappers such as the above. [facebook/immutable-js#519](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/519) isn't promising.

Comment: The following is only my personal opinion. Instead of introducing a new abstract data type I'd solve this problem programmatically by defining a separate function/constructor that takes care of the value equality check while adding entries/constructing the `Map`. I always tend to accept the limitations of JS. Moreover I doubt that objects used as keys in `Map`s really benefit from persistent data structures, since they ought to be rather small, like value objects. Immutable.js seems  to be more suitable for huge data structures like a redux store.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @ftor. You say that the objects used as keys won't benefit from being persistent data structures, but isn't the pertinent question whether the data structure itself—not its keys—benefits from being persistent? Since wrapping appears to be necessary, I now wonder whether we should wrap the native Map type instead and avoid a dependency: [sanctuary-js/sanctuary#233](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary/issues/233).

Comment: Maybe try to use newtype-like wrappers around `Array` and `Number`? Modifying such a crucial property of builtins could be devastating.

Comment: I think not the ability to use reference types as keys but the reliable order and the strict separation of program and data level are the key benefits of the native `Map` type. Anyway, I'm curious how you solve this problem, since I experience a similar one with implementing monoidal `Number`s, `Array`s etc. for a more generic `fold`.

Comment: "Modifying such a crucial property of builtins could be devastating." What do you mean by this, @Bergi? I'm not suggesting modifying any existing behaviour. Are you suggesting that `assoc`iating `[1, 2, 3]`–`'baz'` with an existing map would be very slow because we'd first need to see whether any of the keys is equal to `[1, 2, 3]`? That's a problem, certainly. What do you have in mind for the newtype-like wrappers? Could they solve this problem?

Comment: @davidchambers I mean that modifying global builtins that could be used by others (e.g. libraries you want to use, future versions of libraries your are using etc) is a bad idea, because it might break that other code. The hack is fine when you known and control your environment, but as a library you should not do it.

Comment: @davidchambers You know `newtype` in Haskell? E.g you could use a `List` (with sensible equality) instead of an array, and a `MyNumber` that distinguishes zeroes instead of a plain number.

Comment: "I mean that modifying global builtins that could be used by others […] is a bad idea". I completely agree, @Bergi. I'm not suggesting this. I'm suggesting defining a "newtype" wrapper for either `Immutable.Map` or the native `Map`. Users wouldn't need to know that the newtype makes use of some other Map type internally, nor would other users of that other Map type be affected in any way.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood "*redefine the equality semantics of native types such as Array and Number*". Good you don't want to make a global modification :-) It sounded like defining `Array.prototype.equals` and `Number.prototype.equals` would solve the problem.

Comment: What I mean is that you should use a newtype wrapper around `Array` and `Number` which defines your custom `.equals` method, and then to instantiate the wrapper implicitly for all arrays and numbers that are passed into your wrapped `Map`.

Comment: That clarifies things. Thanks. I see now that "redefine" was a poor word choice.

Comment: I have two answers which may be valuable to you: 1) we create a custom type `Dict` which is capable of associating values to compound data keys, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244545/633183) and 2) a generic object equality function, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233053/633183)

Comment: Didn't realize how old this question was, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Although this was asked long ago I don't see a reference to this simple solution:

```js
const {Map, fromJS} = Immutable

// instead of this:
console.log(
  Map([[[1, 2, 3], 'foo'], [[1, 2, 3], 'bar']]).toString(),
)

// do this:
console.log(
  Map(fromJS([[[1, 2, 3], 'foo'], [[1, 2, 3], 'bar']])).toString()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

By deeply converting the objects using [fromJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) you get the value equality

Comment: This approach doesn't support [`fantasy-land/equals`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#setoid), but it works well for values of built-in types.