# Reducing/Grouping an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774906/3254598) example, I want to group by object in a slightly other way. The outcome should be as follows:

```
[{
  key: "audi"
  items: [
    {
      "make": "audi",
      "model": "r8",
      "year": "2012"
    },
    {
      "make": "audi",
      "model": "rs5",
      "year": "2013"
    }
  ]
},
...
]
```

How can I achieve that? The following code I wrote doesn't do what I want:

```
reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.art] = {key: r[a.art], items: []} || [];
        r[a.art].items.push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

Comment: what is the data you're starting with? what have you tried and what was your error?

Comment: My problem is, that I don't quite understand how the reduction works in the original example. I tried the following code, but it creates a pretty weird result:

`reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.art] = {key: r[a.art], items: []} || [];
        r[a.art].items.push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I figured you were using the same data as in the example you posted, but then I see your code looks for `a.art`, which I have no idea what it is, so I was unable to edit the starting data into your question, and you will have to do that.

Comment: @James: Yes, I copied it from my own code, which uses art instead of make. Sorry ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash table for grouping by `make` and an array for the wanted result.

For every group in `hash`, a new object, like

```
{
    key: a.make,
    items: []
}
```

is created and pushed to the result set.

The hash table is initialized with a really empty object. There are no prototypes, to prevent collision.

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

cars.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hash[a.make]) {
        hash[a.make] = { key: a.make, items: [] };
        result.push(hash[a.make]);
    }
    hash[a.make].items.push(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! What about efficiency? I've heard, that the forEach function isn't the fastest. Is that true?

Comment: you could use a for loop for the index which is actually the fasted for iterating, but i don't think that should be a problem. what is the lenght of the array, you are using?

Comment: @NinaScholz great answer per usual – I hope you don't mind I copied your test `data` for demo purposes in my answer ^_^

Comment: @naomik, never mind, i like your answers (they look like lectures)

Comment: @NinaScholz Around 50 records max. So I guess not a big issue, right?

Comment: @AndréR., it's a small amount.

Answer (score 3):

@Nina's answer is practical, efficient, and definitely the answer you should be reading. However, these problems are interesting to me and I like thinking about solving them in other ways, even if that means making trades.

**Compound data equality in JavaScript**

Testing for compound data equality in JavaScript can be a bother

```js
console.log (1 === 1)         // true
console.log ('a' === 'a')     // true
console.log ([1,2] === [1,2]) // false
console.log ({a:1} === {a:1}) // false
```

This simple-natured equality test can make it somewhat challenging to deal with JavaScript's native `Set` and `Map` too

```js
const m = new Map ()
m.set ([1,2], 'hello')
console.log (m.get ([1,2]))                      // undefined
console.log (m.get (Array.from (m.keys ()) [0])) // 'hello'
```

Bugger! Compound data equality bit us again. `m.get` cannot find the key `[1,2]` because the first key (that we set) `[1,2]` is different from the second key (to get) `[1,2]` – ie, the two instances of `[1,2]` are in different memory locations and are therefore considered (by JavaScript) to be inequal (`!==`)

---

**Compound data equality, take 2**

We don't have to play by JavaScript's rules, if we don't want to. In this part of the answer, we make our own `Dict` (dictionary) compound data type that accepts a function that is used to determine key equality

Imagine `Dict` working something like this

```
const d = Dict (({a} => a)
d.has ({a:1}) // false
d.set ({a:1}, 'hello') .has ({a:1}) // true
d.set ({a:1}, 'hello') .get ({a:1}) // 'hello'
d.get ({a:2}) // undefined
d.set ({a:2}, 'world') .get ({a:2}) // 'world'
```

If we had a data type that worked like `Dict`, then we could easily write the necessary transformation for our data

```
// our Dict type with custom key comparator
const DictByMake =
  Dict (x => x.make)

const dict =
  data.reduce((d, item) =>
    d.set (item, d.has (item)
      ? d.get (item) .concat ([item])
      : [item]), DictByMake ())
```

I say *if we had a data type like `Dict`* because it's good to be optimistic. Why should I make sacrifices and pick a data type incapable of fulfilling my needs when I don't have to? If a type I need doesn't exist, I can just make one. Thanks in advance, JavaScript !

Below I implement `Dict` with *some* consistency to JS's `Set` and `Map` – the most notable difference here is `Dict` is persistent (immutable) (a matter of preference, in this case)

```js
const Pair = (left, right) => ({
  left,
  right
})

const Dict = eq => (pairs=[]) => ({
  equals (x, y) {
    return eq (x) === eq (y)
  },
  has (k) {
    for (const {left} of pairs)
      if (this.equals (k, left))
        return true
    return false
  },
  get (k) {
    for (const {left, right} of pairs)
      if (this.equals (k, left))
        return right
    return undefined
  },
  set (k, v) {
    for (const [i, {left, right}] of pairs.entries ())
      if (this.equals (k, left))
        return Dict (eq) (pairs
          .slice (0, i)
          .concat ([Pair (k, v)])
          .concat (pairs.slice (i+1)))
    return Dict (eq) (pairs.concat ([Pair (k, v)]))
  },
  entries () {
    return {
      *[Symbol.iterator] () {
        for (const {left, right} of pairs)
          yield [eq (left), right]
      }
    }
  }
})

const DictByMake =
  Dict (x => x.make)

const main = data => {
  // build the dict
  const dict =
    data.reduce((d, x) =>
      d.set(x, d.has (x)
        ? [...d.get (x), x]
        : [x]), DictByMake ())
  // convert dict key/value pairs to desired {key, items} shape
  return Array.from (dict.entries (), ([key, items]) =>
      ({ key, items }))
} 

const data = 
  [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }]
  
console.log (main (data))
```

---

**Compound data equality, take 3**

OK, that was a little intense inventing our very own data type ! In the example above, we based `Dict` off of an `Array` (native) of pairs – this naïve implementation detail makes `Dict` inefficient compared to other associative types that instead use a binary search tree or hash table to get/set keys. I used this an example to show how to build a more complex type from a more primitive one, but we could've just as easily made our own Tree type and used that instead.

In reality, we are given `Map` by JavaScript and don't have (get) to worry about *how* it's implemented – and while it doesn't have the *exact* behavior we want, we can adapt its behavior slightly without having to invent an entirely new type from scratch.

Worth noting, `MapBy` is **not** implemented as a  persistent structure here

```js
const MapBy = ord => (map = new Map ()) => ({
  has: k =>
    map.has (ord (k)),
  get: k =>
    map.get (ord (k)),
  set: (k, v) =>
    MapBy (ord) (map.set (ord (k), v)),
  keys: () =>
    map.keys (),
  values: () =>
    map.values (),
  entries: () =>
    map.entries ()
})

// the rest of the program stays exactly the same (with exception to variable names)
const MapByMake =
  MapBy (x => x.make)

const main = data => {
  const map =
    data.reduce((m, x) =>
      m.set(x, m.has (x)
        ? [...m.get (x), x]
        : [x]), MapByMake ())
  return Array.from (map.entries (), ([key, items]) =>
      ({ key, items }))
} 

const data = 
  [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }]
      
console.log (main (data))
```

Comment: great your functional understanding, where i am lacking ... :/ mabe you could help with (not here in the question, but general) how to use monads in js. mabe you have an enlightend link or so.

Comment: Nina, I have many [answers that talk about monads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+monad), almost all using JS. Much of my learning stemmed from [Mostly Adequate Guide](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide) by [Brian Lonsdorf](https://twitter.com/drboolean?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor). He also [has some stuff on egghead](https://egghead.io/instructors/brian-lonsdorf) and [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=brian+lonsdorf) which I found to be very helpful. If you have more questions, I'm happy to help <3