# typescript: generic constraints cause type inference to pick wrong candidate?

Tags: typescript, generics

**TypeScript Version:**  2.6.0-dev.20170826 and 2.4.2

I wonder if I hit some typescript inference bug/limitation, or if my code is simply incorrect. If the code is actually valid, and it's a type inference issue, I'll report a bug to the typescript github.

I'm trying to constrain the `Set` builder to accept only types for which equality is properly defined (to avoid [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557342/custom-equality-semantics-for-immutable-js-data-structures)).

**strange.d.ts**

```
declare module 'strange' {
    export type WithEquality = string|number|boolean|{equals(other: any): boolean; hashCode(): number;};

    export interface Set<T> {
        add(other: T): Set<T>;
    }

    export function makeSetUnsafe<V>(...vals: V[]): Set<V>;
    export function makeSet<V extends WithEquality>(...vals: V[]): Set<V>;
}
```

**strange.ts**

```
///<reference path="./strange.d.ts"/>

import * as S from 'strange';

const x = S.makeSetUnsafe(1,2,3);
x.add(4);

const y = S.makeSet(1,2,3);
y.add(4);
```

**Expected behavior:**
From my understanding the code should compile. Typescript should infer `number` for both examples as the type, and since `number` is an option in `WithEquality`, and the constraint is `T extends WithEquality`, all should be fine.

**Actual behavior:**
The call to `makeSetUnsafe` compiles fine, but the call to `makeSet` fails with this error:

```
strange.ts(9,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type '1 | 2 | 3'.
```

Adding the generic constraint to check that the generic type of the `Set` interface extends `WithEquality` causes the inference to pick `1|2|3` instead of `number` for `T`.

Giving the type explicitly with `const y = S.makeSet<number>(1,2,3);` makes it build, so it seems adding the generic constraint makes the type inference pick another type.

In fact I can reproduce the issue even with the simpler

```
export type WithEquality = number;
```

A good answer would explain why this code is wrong, hopefully give a typescript implementation allowing to express these constraints with the type inference working, or confirm that it's a typescript limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why that happens, check the answer to this issue:
[Type variable constrained to primitive or union type not assignable to it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1935).

You can fix it like this:

```
export function makeSet<V>(...vals: Array<V & WithEquality>): Set<V>;
```

And then:

```
const y = makeSet2(1,2,3);
y.add(4); // fine
const z = makeSet(/a*/); // error
```