# Compare two objects and add missing key to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got two `JavaScript` `objects`. I want to compare both `objects` to one another. If `object 1` has a `key` which is missing in `object 2` add this `key` to `object 2`.

But this must also be the case if `object 2` has a `key` which is missing in `object 1`.

**So for example, `object 1` looks like this.**

```
var object_1 = {
    "Address": "Address",
    "AccessDeniedText": "You do not have access to the page you requested.<br>Use the navigation menu on the left to select a page you want to open.",
    "Basket": "Shopping cart",
    "BasketVAT": "VAT {0}"
    ...
};
```

**`object 2` looks like this.**

```
var object_2 = {
    "Address": "Address",
    "Basket": "Shopping cart",
    ...
};
```

In `object 2` the `key` *AccessDeniedText* and *BasketVAT* are missing.

**Expected result**
What i now want is to have an new `object`, lets say `object 3` that would now output the following.

```
var object_3 = {
    "Address": "Address",
    "AccessDeniedText": "",  // I can fill this missing text
    "Basket": "Shopping cart",
    "BasketVAT": "" // I can fill this missing text
}
```

I tried to use `$.each()` and `for(key in object)`. However, this made my whole browser crash. Not so wierd, because each `object` has more then a 1000 rows.

I also tried to awnser of this question: [Javascript: compare two objects, and get key-value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232823/javascript-compare-two-objects-and-get-key-value-pair)
It didn't work for me.

Is there a simple way to do it? Without my browser crashing of the heavy payload? I dont care using `jQuery`.

Comment: It looks like you're asking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: That overwrites properties doens't it? From a voted comment `This doesn't work if objects have same name attributes, and you would also want to merge the attributes.`. Thats not exacly what i want.

Comment: Iterating over 1000 props shouldn't crash browser. It is nothing for modern browsers.

Comment: The duplicate is not what i want... It merges 2 objects. I dont want to merge both `key` and `value` only the `key` ...