# Deep Object Compare using Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, arrow-functions

I'm attempting deep object comparison using recursion, but my function is returning `undefined`.

I know there are better ways to compare objects (IE `JSON.Stringify()`) but I'm not understanding why my function is returning `undefined`.

```js
function deepObjCompare(obj1, obj2) {

  Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
    const key1 = obj1[key];
    const key2 = obj2[key];

    if (key2) {
      if (typeof key1 === "object" && key1 !== null) {
        deepObjCompare(key1, key2);
      } else if (key1 === key2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}

const obj1 = {
  name: "Bill",
  address: {
    cityNow: "Paris",
    cityFuture: "NYC"
  },
  age: 39
};

const obj2 = {
  name: "Bill",
  address: {
    cityNow: "Paris",
    cityFuture: "NYC"
  },
  age: 39
};

const obj3 = {
  name: "Bob",
  address: "Paris",
  age: 39
};

console.log(deepObjCompare(obj1, obj3));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33232823/633183

Comment: You will want to use `.every`. Never use `forEach`

Comment: This program has a lot of complexity that is easily overlooked. I encourage you to see my answer to the above Q&A

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not a proper way to compare objects, as they might be serialised in different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three main issues here:

- `deepObjCompare` lacks a return statement, which is why it is implicitly returning `undefined`.
- The `.forEach` method always returns `undefined`, so you'll want to change that to another method that will return an actual value. I think `.every` is what you're after here.
- You do not return the result of your recursive call.

All together, that would change your snippet to the following:

```js
function deepObjCompare(obj1, obj2) {

  return Object.keys(obj1).every((key) => { // Use .every and return the result!
    const key1 = obj1[key];
    const key2 = obj2[key];

    if (key2) {
      if (typeof key1 === "object" && key1 !== null) {
        return deepObjCompare(key1, key2); // Return the result of your recursive call!
      } else if (key1 === key2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}

const obj1 = {
  name: "Bill",
  address: {
    cityNow: "Paris",
    cityFuture: "NYC"
  },
  age: 39
};

const obj2 = {
  name: "Bill",
  address: {
    cityNow: "Paris",
    cityFuture: "NYC"
  },
  age: 39
};

const obj3 = {
  name: "Bob",
  address: "Paris",
  age: 39
};

console.log(deepObjCompare(obj1, obj3)); // false
console.log(deepObjCompare(obj1, obj2)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't return from a `forEach` loop, and you have to return the recursive call:

```js
function deepObjCompare(obj1, obj2) {

  let keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  return keys.every((key) => { // use a for-of loop instead of forEach
    const key1 = obj1[key];
    const key2 = obj2[key];

    if (key2) {
      if (typeof key1 === "object" && key1 !== null) {
         return deepObjCompare(key1, key2); // return the recursive call
      } else if (key1 === key2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}

const obj1 = {name: "Bill",address: {cityNow: "Paris",cityFuture: "NYC"},age: 39};
const obj2 = {name: "Bill",address: {cityNow: "Paris",cityFuture: "NYC"},age: 39};
const obj3 = {name: "Bill",address: "Paris",age: 39};

console.log("Are Obj1 and Obj3 equal? ",deepObjCompare(obj1, obj3));
console.log("Are Obj1 and Obj2 equal? ",deepObjCompare(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score -1):

There are actually a number of things I see that are wrong with this implementation. But as to why it's returning `undefined` - that's because your function never actually `return`s anything. All your `return` statements are inside the function passed to `forEach`, and therefore do nothing with regard to the outer `deepObjCompare`.

Comment: Can someone please explain the down votes? I appreciate I didn't give a solution to comparing objects, and therefore it's not as good as other answers given. But my time was limited and it sounded like the OP just wanted to know why they were getting `undefined`, with a view to fixing it themselves. And I believe my answer is correct on that point. No hard feelings, I'm just relatively new to participating on SO and would like to learn from my mistakes.