# Key value pair intersection of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, intersection

I would like to know if there is a way to find the intersection of a key value pair in an array of objects. Let's say you have an array of three objects which all have the same keys like this :

```
    arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "stringB"
        "c": {"c1":1,
            "c2": "stringC2"
            }
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "stringBdiff"
        "c": {"c1":1,
            "c2": "stringC2"
            }
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "stringB"
        "c": {"c1":1,
            "c2": "stringC2"
            }
    }
  ]
```

I would like to find the common key value pairs of the three objects:

```
output= [
 {"a":1}, 
 {"c": {"c1":1, 
        "c2":"stringC2"
       }
 }
]
```

This is what I have done so far, it works but not on nested objects. I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it and one that could work on nested object as well.

```js
    let properties;
    let commonFound = false;
    let notCommonFound = false;
   const commonValues = [];
   let value;
   const initialArray = [{
   "a": 2,
   "b": "stringB",
   "c": {
     "c1": 1,
     "c2": "stringC2"
   }
  },
  {
   "a": 1,
   "b": "stringB",
   "c": {
     "c1": 2,
     "c2": "stringC2"
   }
  },
  {
   "a": 1,
   "b": "stringB",
   "c": {
     "c1": 2,
     "c2": "stringC2"
   }
  }
  
  ];
   
   const commonStorage = [];
   const  reference = initialArray[0];
   properties = Object.keys(reference);
   properties.forEach((property) => {
       for (let i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
        commonFound = false;
        notCommonFound = false;
          for (let j = 0; j <i ; j++) {        
              if (initialArray[i][property] === initialArray[j][property]) {
                commonFound = true;
                value = initialArray[i][property];
                }
              else {
               notCommonFound = true;
               value = [];
               }         
          }
        }
       if (commonFound && !notCommonFound) {
          commonStorage.push({[property] : value});
       }
   });
     
  console.log(commonStorage);
```

Comment: so basically you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: Try reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233053/633183) – I'll work on an adaptation that answers this question more directly when I get the time :D

Comment: do all the objects have the same keys, or can some objects have different keys. If the keys are all the same you can use something like lodash to do the deep equal checking with `_.isEqual(obj1, obj2);`.

Comment: Actually I want to keep the duplicates and remove everything else. @duxfox-- all the objects have the same keys exactly and the same number of keys. I can not use deep equality because some values will be different between objects so objects won't be equals but some key value pair might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we implement `intersect` we'll first look at how we expect it to behave –

```
console.log
  ( intersect
      ( { a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 }
      , { a: 1, c: 3, d: 5 }
      )
      // { a: 1 }

  , intersect
      ( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 ]
      , [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 ]
      )
      // [ 1, 2, 3, <1 empty item>, 6 ]

  , intersect
      ( [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 4, b: 5 }, ]
      , [ { a: 1 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 6 }, ]
      )
      // [ { a: 1 }, <1 empty item>, { a: 4 } ]

  , intersect
      ( { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2 ]    } } } }
      , { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } } }
      )
      // { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2 ] } } } }
  )
```

Challenging problems like this one are made easier by breaking them down into smaller parts. To implement `intersect` we will plan to `merge` two calls to `intersect1`, each contributing one *side* of the computed result –

```
const intersect = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  merge
    ( intersect1 (left, right)
    , intersect1 (right, left)
    )
```

Implementing `intersect1` is remains relatively complex due to the need to support both objects *and* arrays – the sequence of `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` helps maintain a flow of the program

```
const intersect1 = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (left)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          // both values are objects
          isObject (v) && isObject (right[k])
            ? [ k, intersect (v, right[k]) ]
          // both values are "equal"
          : v === right[k]
            ? [ k, v ]
          // otherwise
          : [ k, {} ]
      )
    .filter
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v)
            ? Object.keys (v) .length > 0
            : true
      )
    .reduce
      ( assign
      , isArray (left) && isArray (right) ? [] : {}
      )
```

Lastly we implement `merge` the same way we did in [the other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233053/633183) –

```
const merge = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (right)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (left [k])
            ? [ k, merge (left [k], v) ]
            : [ k, v ]
      )
    .reduce (assign, left)
```

The final dependencies –

```
const isObject = x =>
  Object (x) === x

const isArray =
  Array.isArray

const assign = (o, [ k, v ]) =>
  (o [k] = v, o)
```

Verify the complete program works in your browser below –

```js
const isObject = x =>
  Object (x) === x

const isArray =
  Array.isArray

const assign = (o, [ k, v ]) =>
  (o [k] = v, o)

const merge = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (right)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (left [k])
            ? [ k, merge (left [k], v) ]
            : [ k, v ]
      )
    .reduce (assign, left)

const intersect = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  merge
    ( intersect1 (left, right)
    , intersect1 (right, left)
    )

const intersect1 = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (left)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (right[k])
            ? [ k, intersect (v, right[k]) ]
            : v === right[k]
              ? [ k, v ]
              : [ k, {} ]
      )
    .filter
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v)
            ? Object.keys (v) .length > 0
            : true
      )
    .reduce
      ( assign
      , isArray (left) && isArray (right) ? [] : {}
      )

console.log
  ( intersect
      ( { a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 }
      , { a: 1, c: 3, d: 5 }
      )
      // { a: 1 }

  , intersect
      ( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 ]
      , [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 ]
      )
      // [ 1, 2, 3, <1 empty item>, 6 ]

  , intersect
      ( [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 4, b: 5 }, ]
      , [ { a: 1 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 6 }, ]
      )
      // [ { a: 1 }, <1 empty item>, { a: 4 } ]

  , intersect
      ( { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2 ]    } } } }
      , { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } } }
      )
      // { a: { b: { c: { d: [ 1, 2 ] } } } }
  )
```

---

**intersectAll**

Above `intersect` only accepts two inputs and in your question you want to compute the intersect of 2+ objects. We implement `intersectAll` as follows -

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const intersectAll = (x = None, ...xs) =>
  x === None
    ? {}
    : xs .reduce (intersect, x)

console.log
  ( intersectAll
      ( { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3, e: 4 } }
      , { a: 1, b: 9, c: { d: 3, e: 4 } }
      , { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3, e: 5 } }
      )
      // { a: 1, c: { d: 3 } }

  , intersectAll
      ( { a: 1 }
      , { b: 2 }
      , { c: 3 }
      )
      // {}

  , intersectAll
      ()
      // {}
  )
```

Verify the results in your browser –

```js
const isObject = x =>
  Object (x) === x

const isArray =
  Array.isArray

const assign = (o, [ k, v ]) =>
  (o [k] = v, o)

const merge = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (right)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (left [k])
            ? [ k, merge (left [k], v) ]
            : [ k, v ]
      )
    .reduce (assign, left)

const intersect = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  merge
    ( intersect1 (left, right)
    , intersect1 (right, left)
    )

const intersect1 = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (left)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (right[k])
            ? [ k, intersect (v, right[k]) ]
            : v === right[k]
              ? [ k, v ]
              : [ k, {} ]
      )
    .filter
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v)
            ? Object.keys (v) .length > 0
            : true
      )
    .reduce
      ( assign
      , isArray (left) && isArray (right) ? [] : {}
      )

const None =
  Symbol ()

const intersectAll = (x = None, ...xs) =>
  x === None
    ? {}
    : xs .reduce (intersect, x)
    
console.log
  ( intersectAll
      ( { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3, e: 4 } }
      , { a: 1, b: 9, c: { d: 3, e: 4 } }
      , { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3, e: 5 } }
      )
      // { a: 1, c: { d: 3 } }

  , intersectAll
      ( { a: 1 }
      , { b: 2 }
      , { c: 3 }
      )
      // {}
      
  , intersectAll
      ()
      // {}
  )
```

---

**remarks**

You'll want to consider some things like –

```
intersect
  ( { a: someFunc, b: x => x * 2, c: /foo/, d: 1 }
  , { a: someFunc, b: x => x * 3, c: /foo/, d: 1 }
  )
  // { d: 1 }                          (actual)
  // { a: someFunc, c: /foo/, d: 1 }   (expected)
```

We're testing for what's considered *equal* here in `intersect1` –

```
const intersect1 = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
  Object.entries (left)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          isObject (v) && isObject (right[k])
            ? [ k, intersect (v, right[k]) ]
            : v === right[k] // <-- equality?
              ? [ k, v ]
              : [ k, {} ]
      )
    .filter
      ( ...
```

If we want to support things like checking for equality of Functions, RegExps, or other objects, this is where we would make the necessary modifications

---

**recursive diff**

In [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232823/how-to-compare-two-objects-and-get-key-value-pairs-of-their-differences/33233053#33233053) we compute the recursive `diff` of two objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user633183! However would it be possible to modify unionAll to accept an array of objects instead of objects or arrays? In my situation the input is a dynamically generated array containing the objects.

Comment: @JordanA29 sure, simply update `const unionAll = (x = None, ...xs) =>` to `const unionAll = ([ x = None, ...xs ]) =>`