# JS ES6 constructing an object with orignal and attributes similar to Laravel collections

Tags: javascript, laravel, oop, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to create an extensible base model class that will allow for diffing between `original` and `attributes` so that I can create a `getDirty()` method on the child class that will diff between the objects `orignal` properties and any changed `attributes`. Here's the class so far:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

class Model {

  constructor (attributes) {
  this.original = attributes
  this.attributes = attributes

  Object.keys(this.attributes).forEach((property) => {
    Object.defineProperty(this, property, {
      get: () => this.getAttribute(property),
      set: (value) => this.setAttribute(property, value)
    })
  })
  }

  getAttribute (key) {
    return this.attributes[key]
  }

  setAttribute (key, value) {
    this.attributes[key] = value
  }

  static fetchById (id) {
    if (!id) {
      throw new Error('Cannot fetch without id')
    }

  return Vue.prototype.$http
    .get(this.endpoint + id)
    .then(response => {
      return new this(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }
}

export default Model
```

With this code, I am creating an account by extending this Model with an Account model:

```
import Model from './Model'
import Vue from 'vue'

class Account extends Model {

  static endpoint = '/api/accounts/'

  getOwner () {
    if (this.company_owner_uuid) {
      return 'company'
    }
    return 'person'
  }

  getDirty = () => {
    // This log is showing the changed name from the component input, rather than the original
    console.log(this.original.person_owner.first_name)
    const diff = Object.keys(this.original).reduce((diff, key) => {
      if (this.attributes[key] === this.original[key]) return diff
      return {
        ...diff,
        [key]: this.original[key]
      }
    }, {})

    return diff
  }

  update () {
     return Vue.prototype.$http
       .put(`${Account.endpoint}/${this.account_uuid}`, this.getDirty())
       .then(response => {
         console.log(response)
          return response.data
       })
       .catch(error => {
         console.error(error)
       })
  }
}

export default Account
```

And in my component:

```
Account.fetchById(this.id).then(account => {
  this.account = account
})
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  .then(() => {
    // hide loading or whatever after promise is fully resolved...
  })
```

This all works really so far aside from when I make a change to the account, it mutates both `this.original` and `this.attributes`. Does anyone have a recommendation for creating an immutable `this.original` version of the account object that is passed into the constructor that could then be used for comparison to the mutated `attributes`? My end goal here is to only send any modified attributes to the back-end (I'm using Laravel 5.8). Thanks!

Comment: You need to make a copy of attributes instead of having two references to the same object. If attributes is guaranteed to always be shallow (no nested arrays/objects) you can do this: `this.original = { ...attributes };`. Otherwise you'll need to make a deep copy.

Comment: You might be interested in this [recursive diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232823/how-to-compare-two-objects-and-get-key-value-pairs-of-their-differences/33233053#33233053) I wrote awhile back

Comment: I've tried using the object spread operator and am getting the same result. Also, there are nested arrays/objects. How do I make a deep copy?

Comment: Update: this works for cloning: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributes)).